# Download and display PDF with Trigger.io and jQuery Mobile

Tags: pdf, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, trigger.io

We are going to develop a mobile app (iOS and Android), which should provide downloading and storing several user-selected PDF files and viewing them within the app (iOS with WebView) or with an external PDF Viewer (Android).

My Question is: Is this possible with Trigger.io? I didn't find anything concerning this in the official documentation. Can we do something with the file or the child browser / tabs module? If yes, do you have any examples?

Note: We will use Backbone.js and jQuery Mobile as additional libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android webview doesn't allow for inline opening of PDFs - you can test that by opening e.g. http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/trigger.io-whitepaper.pdf in your stock browser.

On iOS, you can use:

```
forge.tools.getURL('my_file.pdf',
  function (file) {
    forge.tabs.open(file);
  }
);
```

But that won't work on Android (tested on 2.3, 3 and 4.0).

Comment: This was very helpful, especially together with http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/features/cache.html.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - yes.

Downloading, storing, then showing/referencing later can definitely be done.  Check out the forge.file [documentation](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/file.html#modules-file).

I have not tried the child browser feature yet.  Although the tabs module will work, I think its best to just let the device (and its user settings) decide how to display/render the PDF.  I am only saying this because my devices (especially the Android ones... 2.3 and 4.x) tend to behave differently.  Either way... the device's "back button" always gets me back to where I left off in my trigger.io app.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful too, but a little bit more generic than James' answer :-)